# Facebook contact sync in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: contacts, sync, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, facebook

The rivalry between Google and Facebook seems to have gotten in the way of a really useful feature from Gingerbread: Facebook contact sync.  Currently my Verizon Galaxy Nexus has the ability to add accounts for Google, Twitter, LinkedIn.  There is even a Facebook entry in the add account list.  However, clicking that does nothing.

I see that in 4.0.3 there are new social contacts APIs that will let 3rd parties extend this feature with [checkins and posts](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.3.html).  Is there a way to enable Facebook contact syncing in ICS (with or without 4.0.3)?

Comment: This is one area where manufacturer customizations are better. HTC's Sense does a great job of social network integration, it even supports Flickr so you can see your contacts' latest photos.

Comment: @Rex: I have only used Sense on someone else's phone, but I was really unimpressed.  It may add some useful features, but personally I think features like social network integration should be built-in.  Maybe Sense has gotten better since I last used it (admittedly it was more than a year ago).

Comment: Yes, sense 3.0 is the newest. Had very impressive widgets and theme support. You can also customize the lock screen in multiple layouts, and directly open some apps from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Hax Sync](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mots.haxsync&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5tb3RzLmhheHN5bmMiXQ..) on my Nexus. Works perfectly for ICS, it will sync high quality photos (if they are available to sync). I highly recommend it.

Comment: All 3rd party apps in market doesn't sync contact phone number details. (I dont think that contact sync only for pictures will be useful) - HexSync also sync contact details - except phone numbers. Too bad :(

Comment: @swapnil I don't think the facebook API lets you pull down phone numbers? I think that's what I've heard before

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of 3rd-party apps available on the [Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=facebook%20sync&c=apps) that can help with Facebook contacts sync.  Judging from comments, [Friends Sync](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.watto.program.android.sync.facebook) and other similar apps seem to do the job on ICS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll leave this open for a while longer to see if anyone has 1st party solutions (native Android trick or something directly from Facebook).  If nothing comes up I'll accept your answer.

Comment: If you look for the official facebook app on the market, you won't find anything else offered by them, so it's highly unlikely that there would offer something else.